# How to reset Redux toolkit query state?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In Redux toolkit query we write as follows:

```js
const [purchase, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess }] = useCreateOneSaleMutation()
```

is there a way I can reset the values of isError and isSuccess back to **false** after they change because of a query happen?

Comment: you mean they don't reset  ```isLoading``` etc. every fetch to ```useCreateOneSaleMutation``` endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The useMutation hook returns a reset function in its results, see documentation [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usemutation) so in your case you could write.

```
const [purchase, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, reset }] = useCreateOneSaleMutation();
reset();
```

from the documentation:

```
type UseMutationResult<T> = {
  // Base query state
  originalArgs?: unknown // Arguments passed to the latest mutation call. Not available if using the `fixedCacheKey` option
  data?: T // Returned result if present
  error?: unknown // Error result if present
  endpointName?: string // The name of the given endpoint for the mutation
  fulfilledTimestamp?: number // Timestamp for when the mutation was completed

  // Derived request status booleans
  isUninitialized: boolean // Mutation has not been fired yet
  isLoading: boolean // Mutation has been fired and is awaiting a response
  isSuccess: boolean // Mutation has data from a successful call
  isError: boolean // Mutation is currently in an "error" state
  startedTimeStamp?: number // Timestamp for when the latest mutation was initiated

  reset: () => void // A method to manually unsubscribe from the mutation call and reset the result to the uninitialized state
}
```

Comment: what about queries ? useQuery doesnt return reset. For example, I use useQuery, and api returns error. Then, I catch the error and show toast or smt, then immediately I want to navigate another page and unmount the component which did the request. There is still error state on redux, and if I go to the previous page which has error, on the initial render, it shows error. I want to clear error state when component unmounted

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing i did something playaround. I dont remember the exact solution but, I just dispatched normal handmade action, but not created by rtk's builder which reaches and clears redux state